# MySQL: SELECT inside SELECT IF() statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Can I have something like this?

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id = 1) = 0, 1, <nothing_to_happen>) AS Available
```

My goal is select this:

```
+---------+
|Available|
+---------+
|1        |
+---------+
```

Only if there is no row selected from this query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

If the row with id = 1 exists in table, I want my query to return zero rows! Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  1
FROM    dual
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = 1
        )
```

Comment: Using LEFT JOIN and filtering for NULL-s is another, probably faster solution.

Comment: It was marginally faster in `5.1`, and become the same in `5.5`.

Comment: Since when does MySQL have the `dual` table?

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(id) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS Available
FROM `TABLE`
WHERE id = 1
```